# Testing aiohttp & mongo with pytest

Tags: python, mongodb, pytest, aiohttp

I have a simple coroutine `register` that accepts login and password
as post arguments, then it goes into the database and so on.
The problem I have is that I do not know how to test the coroutine.

I followed examples from 
https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html.

And everything seemed easy until I started writing tests myself.

Code for  `test_register.py`

```
from main import make_app
pytest_plugins = 'aiohttp.pytest_plugin'


@pytest.fixture
def cli(loop, test_client):
    return loop.run_until_complete(test_client(make_app))

async def test_register(cli):
    resp = await cli.post('/register', data={'login': 'emil', 'password': 'qwerty'})
    assert resp.status == 200
    text = await resp.text()
```

And `register.py`

```
from settings import db

async def register(request):
    post_data = await request.post()
    print('Gotta: ', post_data)
    login, password = post_data['login'], post_data['password']
    matches = await db.users.find({'login': login}).count()
    ...
```

`main.py`

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import routes


def make_app(loop=None):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    for route in routes:
        app.router.add_route(route.method, route.url, route.handler)
    return app


def main():
    web.run_app(make_app())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`settings.py`

```
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
DBNAME = 'testdb'
db = AsyncIOMotorClient()[DBNAME]
```

And then I ran `py.test test_register.py` and it got stuck on database operation 
`matches = await db.users.find({'login': login}).count()`

Comment: Please provide a code for `make_app` function. And what is `db`? Is it global object?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov edited the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your problem is **global variable usage**.

I suggest the following changes:

```
from aiohttp import web
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from routes import routes

def make_app(loop=None):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    DBNAME = 'testdb'
    mongo = AsyncIOMotorClient(io_loop=loop)
    db = mongo[DBNAME]
    app['db'] = db

    async def cleanup(app):
        mongo.close()

    app.on_cleanup.append(cleanup)

    for route in routes:
        app.router.add_route(route.method, route.url, route.handler)
    return app
```

register.py

```
async def register(request):
    post_data = await request.post()
    print('Gotta: ', post_data)
    login, password = post_data['login'], post_data['password']
    matches = await request.app['db'].users.find(
        {'login': login}).count()
    ...
```

Pushing common-used objects into application's storage is an **appreciated way** for handling database connections etc.